# Checking index like pattern with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I try to check a index string (e.g. `$string = "[index]"`) with a regular expression. This index must be checked against the illegal characters `[` and `]` inside the index name. So for example `[in[dex]` must fail.

My first try:

```
/^\[[^\[\]]*\]$/
```

So the the string must start and end with `[` and `]`. With a negated character class I now try to make inline square brackets illegal but this doesn't work propably.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced,
Johnny

---

**Edit:** I'm very confused. I rerun the tests I wrote for this and it works fine now. Think I have missed something when working in the history of my editor. Thanks for help to everyone.

Comment: You say this does not work properly. Give an example that behaves differently than you expect. The command line `php -r 'echo preg_match("/^\[[^\[\]]*\]$/", "[in[dex]");'` prints a `0`; just as expected

Comment: Are you using preg or ereg?  If you're using ereg, it won't work.  See my post below.

Comment: I'm very confused. I ran different tests which all failed. Now I want to rewind this to post some examples and everything works fine. @Ryan Gross: I use preg_match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `/^\[[^[\]]+\]$/` worked for me.

```
/^\[[^[\]]+\]$/.test("[index]") // true
/^\[[^[\]]+\]$/.test("[in[dex]") // false
/^\[[^[\]]+\]$/.test("[in]dex]") // false
```

1. `/^\[` begins with a bracket
2. `[^` open "not" syntax
3. `[\]` exclusion characters
4. `]+` close not and say we only want 1+ things which pass the not syntax (change to asterisk to match [])
5. `\]$/` Expression will end with the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work using preg_match.  If you are using ereg, then it will not work.  Ereg has been deprecated [as of PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php).  I tried your regex out at regextester.com against the following, and it worked under preg and failed under ereg.

```
[index]
[in[dex]
[in[de]x]
d[index]
[inde]x]
[index]d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\[[^][]+\]$/
```

Is that what you're looking for?

- Match a [ character
- Match a single character NOT present in the list "]["
  Between 1 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Match a ] character

Comment: `[\[]`? Either use `\[` or `[[]`, but both? (Same goes for `[\]]`.)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see right now that your correct regex wouldn't work is if you didn't escape it properly when quoting in PHP. It should be quoted something like: `"/^\\[[^[\\]]*\\]$/"`.